How to clip a raster on all zoom level
I'm trying to clip a raster (mbtiles) with multiple zoom level to keep only the area covered by a polygon.
I've been trying to do it with the GDAL feature in QGIS but it seems to keep only the last zoom level and delete the other. Am I missing some parameter or options?

With MBTiles output you must create the lower zoom levels afterwards with gdaladdo https://gdal.org/en/latest/drivers/raster/mbtiles.html#overviews-raster.
Some other drivers, especially GeoTIFF and COG drivers, can copy the overviews, see COPY_SRC_OVERVIEWS=YES option in https://gdal.org/en/latest/drivers/raster/gtiff.html#raster-gtiff. If you want to save the clipped output into GeoTIFF then this option can be used with QGIS through "Additional creation options" in "Advanced Parameters".

ah i should precise that my mbtiles have different pictures depending on zoom level; so i cannot rework them backward

That may get complicated. I do not believe that GDAL can do that with MBTiles. I would try COG by copying source overviews. With VRT it is doable but may require manual editing of the vrt file. GeoPackage raster might work but I am not sure how to add data into existing tables. Good luck with your trials.

This is very easy to accomplish, using the new Georeferencer Extension plugin.

Install the Georeferencer Extension plugin from the plugin store
Open the georeferencer (Layer > Georeferencer) and drag&drop your MBTiles file into the georeferencer map canvas
Select the clipping boundary feature from the main map canvas and copy the feature to the clipboard (Edit > Copy Features). Be sure that you have configured Plain Text, WKT Geometry format for the feature copy (Settings > Options... > Data Sources > Feature Attribute and Table: Copy feature as). If you need a country border as boundary, you can load the world map as new layer (just enter world into the coordinate display at the bottom) and select a specific country from this layer.
Click the rocket symbol from the georeferencer toolbar, set the correct target/cutline SRS and copy the clipboard content into the WKT field. Enable Create Alpha Channel and Load in QGIS when done and press OK.
Enjoy


Please confirm that this tool copies also the overviews.

@user30184 a MBTiles file is like an image pyramid. The Georeferencer Extension keeps all zoom levels while clipping the image.

The documentation does not mention any other output format than GDAL virtual raster (VRT). That is great for many use cases but not necessarily what the OP wants. Maybe they want to clip the file physically. But of course the vrt can be materialized to other formats with gdal_translate. Copying overviews into a physical file remains the same and gdaladdo may be needed. VRT output from the georeferencer is a very welcome feature.

Ok, if the main goal is to get a clipped MBTiles file, then VRT is no option. Mapproxy is able to clip a MBTiles file into a new one during a seed.
